# How to send the payment_method_nonce to the server?

Tags: yii2, braintree, yii2-advanced-app

My server is built with the yii2 Advanced framework.

I have integrated the Braintree Drop-In form.

The documentation says an invisible payment_method_nonce is created. My question is how should I send this to the server?

On clicking the default submit button in the Drop-In form (filled with one of the test card details) it accepts the info (UI changes with new Change payment method button) but the Post call never happens/doesn't reach the server.

How do I send the payment_method_nonce to the server?

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.

This is the yii2 view code I used:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<div id="payment-form"></div>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
var clientToken ='<?php echo $var ;?>';
braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
</script>
```

Basic stuff with just the drop-in div